# Input logic error for Connect 4 game in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have coded Connect 4 in C++. The program mostly works, but there is a logic error in the player_turn function.

connect4.cpp:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void setup_grid();
    void display_grid();
    void player_turn(char);
    bool four_in_a_row(char);

    char grid[6][7];

    int main()
    {
        char player = '1';

        setup_grid();
        system("cls");

        while(true)
        {       
            display_grid();
            player_turn(player);

            if(four_in_a_row(player))
            {
                system("cls");
                display_grid();
                std::cout << "Player " << player << " has won!" << std::endl;
                goto end;
            }

            if(player == '1')
                player = '2';
            else if(player == '2')
                player = '1';

            system("cls");
        }

    end:
        std::cin.get();
        std::cin.get();
        return 0;
    }

    void setup_grid()
    {   
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
                grid[i][j] = '0';
    }

    void display_grid()
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter a column number (1-7) to put a piece into that column." << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
                std::cout << grid[i][j] << ' ';

            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    void player_turn(char player)
    {
        int column_number;

    input:
        std::cout << "Player " << player << ": ";

        std::cin >> column_number;

        column_number--;

        if(grid[0][column_number] != '0')
        {
            std::cout << "Column is full." << std::endl;
            goto input;
        }
        if((column_number < 1) || (column_number > 7))
        {
            std::cout << "That number was not between 1 and 7" << std::endl;
            goto input;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            if(grid[i + 1][column_number] != '0')
            {
                grid[i][column_number] = player;
                break;
            }
            else if(i == 6)
            {
                grid[i][column_number] = player;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    bool four_in_a_row(char player)
    {
        // Horizontal check:

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)

            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)

                if(grid[i][j] == player && grid[i][j+1] == player)
                    if(grid[i][j+2] == player && grid[i][j+3] == player)
                        return true;

        // Vertical check:

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)

            for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++)

                if(grid[i][j] == player && grid[i+1][j] == player)
                    if(grid[i+2][j] == player && grid[i+3][j] == player)
                        return true;

        // Diagonal check:

        for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
            {
                if(grid[y][x] == player)
                {

                    // Diagonally left:
                    if(grid[y+1][x-1] == player)
                    {
                        if(grid[y+2][x-2] == player)
                            if(grid[y+3][x-3] == player)
                                return true;
                    }

                    // Diagonally right: (There is an error here)
                    if(grid[y+1][x+1] == player)
                    {
                        if(grid[y+2][x+2] == player)
                            if(grid[y+3][x+3] == player)
                                return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

If the user types in a 1-digit number above 7, the program puts the piece in the first column instead of printing "That number was not between 1 and 7".

If the user types in 0 or an integer above 9, the program prints "Column is full" which should only print if the column actually exists.

Comment: After `column_number--;` you want to check against 0...6, not 1...7, don't you?

Comment: Please only tag the language used.

Comment: When you used a *debugger*, which line is causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the column number is valid **before** doing anything else with it.

Also, get rid of the `goto` and use a loop instead.

```
do {
    bool valid = true;
    std::cout << "Player " << player << ": ";

    std::cin >> column_number;

    if((column_number < 1) || (column_number > 7))
    {
        std::cout << "That number was not between 1 and 7" << std::endl;
        valid = false;
        continue;
    }

    column_number--;

    if(grid[0][column_number] != '0')
    {
        std::cout << "Column is full." << std::endl;
        valid = false;
    }
} while (!valid);
```

Comment: Thanks. The program works now. But why is a do while loop better than using goto?

Comment: @Ajesh In the vast majority of cases, regular looping constructs such as `while` or `for` are clearer and better structured.  There are very few cases where `goto` makes sense in C and practically none in C++.

Comment: @Ajesh Also, feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.